# How customize bundle folder name in Apache Felix Cache before/after installation?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-felix

I have a very simple application in Maven that uses Apache Felix as an OSGi Framework.

Here is a pom.xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.installer</groupId>
    <artifactId>bundle-installer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In the main class I am just getting the bundle by its path and 
installing it by Apache Felix:

```
package com.example.installer;

import org.apache.felix.framework.Felix;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleException;

import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BundleException {

        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.setProperty("org.osgi.framework.storage", "/Users/johndoe/plugins");

        Felix framework = new Felix(config);
        framework.start();

        framework.getBundleContext().installBundle("file:/Users/johndoe/Desktop/bundle-example-0.0.0.1.jar");

        framework.stop();
    }
}
```

Let me explain what I want to implement. As you see I have changed Felix cache dir to "/Users/johndoe/plugins", i.e. I am going to install plugins programmatically by Felix. This code is working well enough except one thing. After installation each bundle is being installed in the folder like *bundle0, bundle1, ..., bundleN etc*. But I don't like this, I want each bundle to be installed in the folder according Symbolic name like: xmlreader, code-analyzer etc.

Unfortunately it is not possible by setting it in Felix config properties. But I hope that there should be some ready solutions instead inventing the wheel.

How to implement this feature in proper way?

Comment: Why on earth do you want spent such effort to shoot yourself in the foot? That folder is not yours to look at ... it is a proprietary aspect of Felix. Leave it alone and use the standardized OSGi API to get the info.

Comment: Oh, you are right. thanks